# Two sets of wire in a previously unused outlet box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have two sets of wire wired together in a previously unused box. No single breaker shuts down power to the box. Is it possible to have separate circuits wired together in one box without tripping each other and can I just split the duplex outlet without any worries. It is behind a shove in range and will only power the electric for a gas range.

Comment: Add pictures of the box to your question.  It is possible(and done) to have a dulpex outlet on two breakers, if the tab joining the two outlet is removed/broken.  Both breakers should have handle tie or be joined somehow so power is turned off both halves of outlet.  Just joining wires together does not sound right, so adding pictures will help us, help you.

Comment: if it takes two breakers to shut the box down, are they adjacent? Old rules permitted non-tied MWBCs. Not a good idea, but it was allowed at one time. And some MWBCs were non-adjacent (or somone moved a breaker then they became non-adjacent) But adjacent is "normal." And yes, please [edit] to add pictures. MWBCs are VERY common for the required two kitchen countertop circuits.

Comment: Turn off all your breakers and then turn them on one at a time until you find one that lights up this box.  Then turn that off and keep looking.  If you find two, "interesting".  If you find 1, it was a flaw in your testing.  If you find NONE then it's powered from a different panel. Look out by the meter.

Comment: How are you measuring to determine if the box has power after shutting off breakers? Some testers can give false positives.